# UIWebView frame height based on content height

Tags: html, ios, css, uiwebview

I currently have a UIWebView object that is injected with the following html string:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            color: purple;
            background-color: #d8da3d;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content" contenteditable="true"> </div>
    <div style="font-family: Helvetica"> Sample text </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems that with the above html code, the contentSize height of the WebView in question is 548px when in reality, it should much less than that, given that there are only two lines. I also have trued loading a URL request to www.google.com. Based on the breakpoints that I have set, the contentSize does seem to increase by the appropriate amount.

So what I would like to know is whether or not it would be possible to adjust the contentSize height based on the contents of the WebView (or in my case, a WebView set with the above html text). I suspect that I might have to specify some sort of .css parameters such as height or min-height (I have already tried to do this, but to no avail). Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Not sure if this helps, but here is the code that I am using to set the html content. I have included the .html file in the project and I set the WebView (created using the storyboard) html content using the following lines in my View Controller:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"compose" ofType:@"html"];
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

[image]

Edit2: After some tinkering, I think I know what is happening. It seems that int he situation where the WebView's content height is < view height, it will automatically default to the WebView's frame. Through experimentation, it seems that the UIBrowserView's frame changes whenever the UIWebView's frame changes. It seems that I cannot change one without affecting the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only really reliable way to determine the content height of a UIWebView is to do it via Javascript once the HTML is fully rendered.

The problem with getting the height in `webViewDidFinishLoad:` is, that this method is called right after the HTML is loaded into the UIWebView. But that does not mean that the HTML is already fully rendered. This might lead to random and wrong heights.

So to get the real height you have to listen to the onLoad event in the HTML DOM. Then send the height to the UIWebView.

You can find a detailed description on how to do this in this [blog post](http://www.pixeldock.com/blog/set-the-height-of-a-uiwebview-to-the-height-of-its-html-content/) that I wrote a while ago.

EDIT:

So this is a special case, where the HTML content is actually smaller than the UIWebView frame. Getting the height of the `<body>` does not work in this case, because the body always extends to the full frame.

You have to change the HTML a little bit. You have to add an element that wraps your HTML content:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
       <div id="content" contenteditable="true"> </div>
       <div style="font-family: Helvetica"> Sample text </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Then in the Javascript snippet you return the height of that wrapper element:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload = function() { 
      window.location.href = "ready://" + document.getElementById('wrapper').offsetHeight;
   }
</script>
```

This returns the correct height of your HTML content. Just on more thing: because the `<body>` element gets a default margin, you have to set the margin to 0:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
       margin:0;
       color: purple;
       background-color: #d8da3d;
    }
</style>
```

Now you get the correct size and you can move your label according to the UIWebView's height.

Comment: I did follow the post on your blog and it does seem genuinely useful. The problem is that it still appears to be returning a height of 532px. The problem is that I've added a subview to the ScrollView of the WebView that sits below the UIBrowserView. Ideally, I'd want the UIBrowserView to resize to fit its content in order to show the subview that I have added to the bottom.

Comment: Edit: I have added picture to the top to give a better illustration of the issue that I am having.Note that I am already having to scroll down slightly in order to show the subview that I have added. In its default position, the height of the UIBrowserView would take up the height of the screen, causing the red label to be pushed out of view.

Comment: You're right, the body always get's the minimum height of the UIWebView. Please see my edited answer for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView {


    NSLog(@"%f",aWebView.scrollView.contentSize.height);

    CGRect frame = aWebView.frame;
    frame.size.height = aWebView.scrollView.contentSize.height;
    aWebView.frame = frame;
}
```

Comment: Basically, one of the things that I am doing is adding a subview into the scrollview of the WebView (I have created a subclass of UIWebView). I am really aiming to modify the height of the UIBrowserView.